# How to replace celery task with azure service bus in a django application?

Tags: python, django, celery, azure-servicebus-queues

I am asked to use the azure service bus instead of celery in a Django application.

Read the documentation provided but didn't get a clear picture of using service bus instead of a celery task. Any advice provided would be of great help.

Comment: just to repharase - what operations are you performing using celery tasks ?

Comment: @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT I'm using celery to run an asynchronous task and that's working fine. All of a sudden I'm asked to use service bus. Didn't know how to use service bus instead of celery.

Comment: Does your celery get triggered on specific condition?

Comment: Yes it's getting triggered. I want the same thing to happen with service bus if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before getting into it, I would like to highlight the differences between Azure Service Bus and Celery.

**Azure Service Bus :**

Microsoft Azure Service Bus is a fully managed enterprise integration message broker.

You could refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview) to know more about the service bus

**Celery  :**

Distributed task queue. Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing.

I could think of 2 possibilities in your case :

1. You would like to use Service Bus with Celery in place of other
   message brokers.
2. Replace Celery with the Service Bus

**1 : You would like to use Service Bus with Celery in place of other message brokers.**

You could refer this to [understand why celery needs a message broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893988/why-does-celery-needs-a-message-broker).
I am not sure which messaging broker you are using currently, but you could use the [Kombu library](https://github.com/celery/kombu) to meet your requirement.

**Reference for Azure Service Bus :** https://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/stable/reference/kombu.transport.azureservicebus.html

**Reference for others :** https://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/stable/reference/index.html

**2 : Replace Celery with the Service Bus completely**
To meet your requirement :

Consider

- Message senders are producers
- Message receivers are consumers

These are two different application that you will have to work on.

You could refer the below to get more sample code to build on.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples

**Explanation :**

- Every time you would like to execute the actions, you could send
  messages to a topic from the producer client.
- The Consumer Client  - the application that is listening, will receive the message and process the same. You could attach your custom process to it - in that way the your custom process gets executed whenever a message is received at the consumer client end.

The below is sample of the receiving client :

```
from azure.servicebus.aio import SubscriptionClient
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

        
Receiving = True

#Topic 1 receiver : 
conn_str= "<>"
name="Allmessages1"
SubsClient = SubscriptionClient.from_connection_string(conn_str, name)
receiver =  SubsClient.get_receiver()

async def receive_message_from1():
    await receiver.open()
    print("Opening the Receiver for Topic1")
    async with receiver:
      while(Receiving):
        msgs =  await receiver.fetch_next()
        for m in msgs:
            print("Received the message from topic 1.....")
            ##### - Your code to execute when a message is received - ########
            print(str(m))
            ##### - Your code to execute when a message is received - ########
            await m.complete()
            
            
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
topic1receiver = loop.create_task(receive_message_from1())
```

the section between the below line would be instruction that will be executed every time a message is received.

```
##### - Your code to execute when a message is received - ########
```